# Discord.py app_command

Tags: discord.py

How I can solve this Discord.py `app_command`?

I am trying to make a `/react` command using discord.py version 2.2.3.

But I get this error:

> TypeError: unsupported type annotation <class 'discord.emoji.Emoji'>

I tried `guild.emojis`, `bot.get_emoji()`, `discord.PartialEmoji` but none of them are working.

Here is my first code snippet:

```
@app_commands.command(name="react", description="Add Reaction to a message")

async def react(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, emoji: discord.Emoji, message_id: Optional[int] = None):

  if message_id is None:

    message = interaction.channel.fetch_message(interaction.channel.last_message_id)

  else:

    try:

      message = await interaction.channel.fetch_message(int(message_id))

    except discord.NotFound:

      await interaction.response.send_message("Message not found", ephemeral = True)

      return 

  try:

    await message.add_reaction(emoji)

    await interaction.response.send_message("Reaction has been added. please react yourself for them to stay", ephemeral = True)

    asyncio.sleep(7)

    await message.clear_reaction()

  except discord.Forbidden:

    await interaction.response.send_message("I don’t have permission to add reaction to that message", ephemeral = True)

  except discord.HTTPException:

    await interaction.response.send_message("Failed to add reaction", ephemeral = True)
```

And this is the second snippet of code:

```
@app_commands.command()

@app_commands.describe(emoji="Choose an emoji", message_id="Enter a message ID")

async def react(interaction: discord.Interaction, emoji: discord.PartialEmoji, message_id: int = None):

  if message_id:

      message = await interaction.channel.fetch_message(message_id)

  else:

      messages = await interaction.channel.history(limit=2).flatten()

      message = messages[1]

  await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

I was expecting this: `/react emoji::custom_emoji: (optional) message_id: 1234567890`
at `emoji` option it will show me the list of custom emojis of the server, just like what`discord.Role` dose. For `message_id` this option will be optional. If no message id is given bot will react with selected emoji from `emoji` option to recent message of the channel were command has been executed. Else bot will react to given message id's message.

[At `emoji` option I want something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haPbq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error says, `type annotation <class 'discord.emoji.Emoji'>` is not supported. This means that you cannot use the type annotation `discord.Emoji`, i.e. `emoji: discord.Emoji`. You can also use `str` and inout the emoji there.

```py
@app_commands.command()
@app_commands.describe(emoji_name="Name of emoji", message_id="Enter a message ID")
async def react(interaction: discord.Interaction, emoji: str, message_id: int = None):
    try:
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)
    except: 
        await interaction.response.send_message('Invalid emoji', ephemeral=True)
```

Comment: I can use `str`, but I want something like [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haPbq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

### Type-hints

In the docs, it's not super clear but the `discord.emoji` is not a valid type-hint in discord.py. [**here**](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/v2.2.3/discord/app_commands/transformers.py#L709-L727) are the valid type-hints you can use. You can also look at [**this**](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#application-command-object-application-command-option-type) for discord.py option types

What you probably want to use is as follows:

```
@app_commands.command(name="react", description="Add Reaction to a message")
@app_commands.describes(emoji="Pick your emoji")
@app_commands.choices(emoji=[
            app_commands.Choice(name=":emoji1:", value=1),#values can be str or int.
            app_commands.Choice(name=":emoji2:", value="emoji2"),
            ...,
            ])
async def react(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, emoji: str, message_id: Optional[int] = None):
```

This will give you choices that you can use.
You can also give choices using literal from the typing library like here in the [**docs**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#typing-literal)
Example:

```
from typing import Literal
@app_commands.command(name="react", description="Add Reaction to a message")
@app_commands.describes(emoji="Pick your emoji")
async def react(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, emoji: Literal[":emoji1:", ":emoji2:"], message_id: Optional[int] = None):
```

NOTE:
The message_id may also be too long for you to use as an int. In this case, you need to pass it in as a string.

Comment: I put the Typehinds as a heading for me so when I look in my saved I can find it easier.

Comment: I don't want to put every single emoji by my self, I want server's custom emojis name list. Just like in the screenshot.

Comment: @Fakemaster that’s not a type-hint. There’s no type-hint for that. Check out the list of type hints you can use in the answer I posted. It should be the first hyperlink.

Comment: @Fakemaster you might be able to use guild.emoji and somehow turn it into a literal list. Not sure if it will work but make a function called get_emojis(). Use the function to get discord emojis and return a list. (Would have to use discord.utils.get or self.bot.guild.emoji to get the list of emojis on the server.) then in your react cmd `def react` you might be able to do `Literal[]+get_emojis()`. Logically I assume it would work but you would have to try and see. Also make sure you’re getting the names in the form of a str.